# What microphone is suitable for recording voice and acoustic guitar?

Tags: voice, acoustic-guitar, microphones, homerecording

Recently I've been performing several songs along with my **acoustic guitar**, so I'd like to record them. At most I've succeeded in recording myself with a phone, but I get this really masked sound.

As far as I know, what should I do to get a **better quality than a masked phone sound**?

- Record both voice and instrument with only a microphone
- Get a microphone for voice and connect guitar through audio interface

Comment: Or you could use two microphones...

Comment: I answered this same question, but about piano and voice, here:  https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/55101/how-do-i-record-piano-and-voice-music-to-the-best-of-quality/56106#56106

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to record both voice and acoustic guitar you might want a large diafragm microphone. A good one for a nice price can be the the NT1-A from Rode for example, or the Audio-Technica AT 2035. You have many options around 120-200€.

In my case, I use a L.R.Baggs M1 for my acoustic guitar (mine doesn't have a preamp) and complement the sound with an SE Electronics SE 2200a II, both connected to a Roland Octa-Capture USB interface.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you have the chance to connect your guitar directly to your interface and record your voice separately, that would be the best way to go.
Otherwise, the previous option seems to be the best.

Good luck and please share your experience when ready.

Comment: For sure it seems the best one, but I'm worried about if it may is complex to process the audio output. Thanks for answering!